# Run the same systemd script passing to it the same env variable but with a different value?

Tags: systemd, terminal, environment-variables

How to run the same systemd script, multiple times in sequence, each time providing the same env. variable but with a different value? I'd prefer that a variable to be provided dynamically - in the terminal.

Is there a way?

Comment: systemd has templates, where you call something like `systemctl start myservice@foobar` and can use `%I` as foobar in the service file itself, but from your description, I don't know if that would work for your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `Environment=` line with "%: specifiers including templated parameters (`%I` or `%i`)

See `man systemd.exec` for the definition of `Environment=`.

See `man systemd.unit` for the definition of "%" specifiers

---

#### Example

Here I am creating a templated unit called `example@.service`.  This template will pass its name (`%I`) to environment variable `HELLO`.  Then it will print out the environment.

The instance I am starting is called `World`.  In the journal we can see it printed `HELLO=World`.

```
$ systemctl --user cat example@.service 
# $HOME/.config/systemd/user/example@.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=HELLO=%I
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env

$ systemctl --user start example@World.service

$ journalctl --user --since "5 minutes ago" | grep HELLO
Aug 30 22:08:34 stewbian env[56312]: HELLO=World
```

---

The template can only pass one variable.  If you need multiple variables, I'd use my template to pass an environment file:

```
$ cat $HOME/home.env
IP=123.45.67.89
PORT=23412

$ cat $HOME/fred.env
IP=12.34.56.78
PORT=10201

$ systemctl --user cat call@.service
# $HOME/.config/systemd/user/call@.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
EnvironmentFile=%h/%I.env
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env

$ systemctl start --user call@home.service
$ systemctl start --user call@fred.service
$ journalctl --user --since "5 minutes ago"
...
Aug 31 08:06:54 stewbian env[3894]: IP=123.45.67.89
Aug 31 08:06:54 stewbian env[3894]: PORT=23412
Aug 31 08:06:54 stewbian systemd[1199]: Finished call@home.service.
...
Aug 31 08:06:59 stewbian env[3894]: IP=12.34.45.78
Aug 31 08:06:59 stewbian env[3894]: PORT=10201
Aug 31 08:06:59 stewbian systemd[1199]: Finished call@fred.service.
```

Comment: And if I had multiple variables?

Comment: It only supports a single variable.  But that single variable could contain the instructions to load more.  Answer updated